How do I get my linked list passed from header file to main?
I am trying to have a linked list in a header file. the structure is also defined there as well. I am trying to read it in the main file.

"linkedlist.h"

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct ll
{
        int number;
        char *data;
        bool flag;
        struct ll *next;
} ll;


ll* def_variables()
{
        ll *head = NULL;
        ll *first = NULL;
        ll *second = NULL;

        first->number = 20;
        first->data = "ding dong";
        first->flag = true;
        first->next = second;

        second->number = 21;
        second->data = "dong ding";
        second->flag = false;
        second->next=NULL;

        head = first;
        return head;
}


main.cpp

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "linkedlist.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
        ll *iterator;
        iterator = def_variables();
        while(iterator->next !=NULL)
        {
                printf("%s is text\n",iterator->data);
                printf("%d is number\n",iterator->number);
                printf("%d is flag\n",iterator->flag);
                iterator=iterator->next;
        }
}

It compiles, but gives segmentation fault. I am at a loss. Any thoughts are most welcome.
I first put the linked list as an object, and it threw errors. Then I enclosed it in a function that would return the head. However, now there is a segmentation fault.

ll *first = NULL; sets *first to NULL (obviously) - no memory is assigned to it, so you can't do e.g. first->number = 20; and not have it crash. You must allocate memory first.

Please note that wile most of the code could be plain C, you do have a statement that makes it C++.

Also don't define functions in header files. Split it into header and source files. Then include the header file, and build with the source file.

I also recommend you use some better name than plain ll. Descriptive names of types and structures and functions and variables will make the code easier to read, understand and maintain.

Lastly a note about the list and its structure: I recommend that you create different structures for the list, the nodes and the data. It will make the code more flexible and robust.

...and don't use identifiers like l, ll, O (l, ll O) etc anywhere. They are too easily confused with 1, 11 and 0. Code should be clear and human-readable.

main.cpp? That would be main.c.

using namespace std;. That doesn’t exist in C.

Type bool is not a built in type in C. You would have to include a header to use it. Same with values true and false.

In current versions of C, bool is not built-in.  In C99 through C17, it is necessary to include <stdbool.h> to get bool, true, false defined.  In C23 and beyond, it will be a built-in type (and true and false are keywords), and the <stdbool.h> header becomes a vestigial relic that is no longer needed (though it is still provided).

Thanks everyone for your responses. @Denis-Kovalchuk's answer  / 500- Internal Server Error's answer worked perfectly. I understand the bad naming conventions -> this was a very basic test code and not part of a serious one. The proper code will have descriptive names :

You need to allocate memory for the first and second variables:
ll* def_variables()
{
    ll *head = NULL;
    ll *second = malloc(sizeof(ll));
    ll *first = malloc(sizeof(ll));

    ...

    head = first;
    return head;
}

Also, it looks like your current while loop is not outputting the last item in the list. You probably meant something like that:
ll *iterator = def_variables();
while (iterator)
{
    printf("%s is text\n",iterator->data);
    printf("%d is number\n",iterator->number);
    printf("%d is flag\n",iterator->flag);
    iterator = iterator->next;
}


There's no need to cast the results of malloc.

ll *def_variables( void ) { ... would be better. AND, reminding OP to use free(), too...
